# Method Signature change does not automatically build in Jrebel

Tags: intellij-idea, dropwizard, jrebel

I have an issue with using Jrebel.
I am trying to build Dropwizard APIs in Intellij Idea.

Any change in method signature(eg name of parameter or additional parameters) does not reflect automatically in JRebel Build. Stop and Re-run will make it Fix.

Same problem in DAO class at annotated query( @SqlQuery(“any change here will make problems”) )

IDE:- Intellij Idea 13.0.1
Jrebel:- 5.5.0-idea13

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually compile the code? JRebel doesn't build the code for you but relies on the compiler results. Well, if you're on IDEA 13, and the deployment is configured via artifacts, then you can configure IDEA to make the project automatically in Settings | Compiler | Make project automatically - then the IDE will make the project once you have made changes to the code, with some delay thoug (~1.5 seconds).

Second, make sure that **rebel.xml** is included into deployment.

For the problems with changes in SqlQuery annotation - the best you can do is to report such problem to the official JRebel support or to the [forums](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I enable auto Build On But still Problem
I Use Maven, so maven create rebel.xml
I posted the same query in Jrebel Forum
[link](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/issue-method-signature-change-does-not-automatically-build-in-jrebel/#post-40195)